# Problema al modificar una base de datos MySql con PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

espero y estén teniendo un excelente día, quería solicitar ayuda en este caso tengo un problema al intentar modificar los datos de una base de datos de MySQL usando PHP no he sido capaz de encontrar mi fallo y agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.
Este es mi formulario a usar:

[image: Formulario]

Este es mi código a utilizar de php.

```
include 'config.php';
session_start();


if(isset($_POST['PAGO']))
{
 $idusuario= $_SESSION["user"];
 
 $FechaVencimiento  = $_POST['labelVencimiento'];
 $CVV  = $_POST['labelCVV'];
 $NombreTarjeta  = $_POST['labelNombreTarjeta'];
 $NTarjeta  = $_POST['labelNTarjeta'];
 $NumeroTelefono  = $_POST['labelTelefono'];

 $query=$connection->prepare("UPDATE datospago set FechaVencimiento='$FechaVencimiento',CVV='$CVV',NombreTarjeta=$NombreTarjeta,."
         . " NTarjeta='$NTarjeta',NumeroTelefono='$NumeroTelefono' WHERE idusuario='$idusuario'");


 $query->bindParam("idusuario", $idusuario, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
 $query->bindParam("CVV", $CVV, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->bindParam("NombreTarjeta", $NombreTarjeta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->bindParam("NTarjeta", $NTarjeta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->bindParam("NumeroTelefono", $providencia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query->bindParam("FechaVencimiento", $FechaVencimiento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  
 $resultado=$query->execute();
 if($resultado)
 {
     echo "<script> alert('Datos registrados');    
          </script>";

     
 }
 else {
 echo "<script> alert('NOOO PAPUs');   
       </script>";
      }
      
      
}
```

Y este es mi HTML del formulario

```
<div class="form-element">
        <label>Porfavor ingrese su Nombre de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelNombreTarjeta" placeholder="Nombre de tarjeta" required/> 
    </div> 
        
         <div class="form-element">
        
        <label>Porfavor ingrese su Numero de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelNTarjeta" placeholder="Numero de Tarjeta" required/> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Ingreso de CVV</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelCVV" placeholder="CVV" required/> 
    </div>
        
   <div class="form-element">
        <label>Ingrese por ingresar su Numero de telefono</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelTelefono" placeholder="Numero de telefono" required/> 
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Ingrese la fecha de vencimiento de su tarjteta</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelVencimiento" placeholder="####" required/> 
    </div>
        
        
        
     <button type="submit" name="PAGO" value="PAGO">Actualizar datos</button>    
                            </form>
```

Esta es mi base de datos que utilizo para registrar los datos obtenidos:

[image: Base de datos]
Agradecería micho cualquier ayuda y consejo, muchas gracias y que tenga un excelente dia :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, asumo que estamos trabajando con PDO ¿cierto?, si es así continuamos:

Un error (typo) está en la línea `$query = $conection->prepare...` en la parte:
`NombreTarjeta=$NombreTarjeta,."` Debe ser: `NombreTarjeta='$NombreTarjeta',"`

Otro *typo* está en la línea:
`$query->bindParam("NumeroTelefono", $providencia, PDO::PARAM_STR);` ¿de donde apareció la variable `$providencia`?. Debe ser `$NumeroTelefono`.

De todas formas, aunque corrijas lo anterior, seguirá sin funcionar porque está mal empleada la consulta preparada. Estás combinando reemplazo directo en la consulta y el binding tampoco se está haciendo de forma correcta. Leer sobre [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

La consulta y su respectivo bind debe ser:

```
$query=$connection->prepare("UPDATE datospago SET 
    FechaVencimiento=:FechaVencimiento, CVV=:CVV, NombreTarjeta=:NombreTarjeta, 
    NTarjeta=:NTarjeta, NumeroTelefono=:NumeroTelefono 
    WHERE idusuario=:idusuario");

$query->bindParam(":idusuario", $idusuario, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$query->bindParam(":CVV", $CVV, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":NombreTarjeta", $NombreTarjeta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":NTarjeta", $NTarjeta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":NumeroTelefono", $NumeroTelefono, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":FechaVencimiento", $FechaVencimiento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Según la documentación, se aconseja poner como 4to parámetro la longitud de la columna de de la tabla MySQL, por ejemplo:

```
$query->bindParam(":CVV", $CVV, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
```

Finalmente, la tabla no tiene un índice único, por lo que será complicado hacerle un mantenimiento, y todo UPDATE que hagas actualizará todos los registros que coincidan con `$idusuario`.

Comment: Hola aeportugal, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda tu comentario me sirvio mucho y agradezco tus comentarios apenas estoy aprendiendo todo el mundo de la programacion web, muchas gracias de verdad compañero te agradezco de corazon tu ayuda